# How can I setup a has_many associated to look in 2 columns in a db table (category_a_id and category_b_id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, rails-models

I need to be able to link up `categories` with each other.

I have a `category_links` table with 2 columns `category_a_id` and `category_b_id` to hold the `id` of the 2 categories that are linked.

I want to be able to call `Category.find(1).category_links` and it will grab all records with the id 1 from both the `category_a_id` and `category_b_id` columns. Also if a category is destroyed it will delete any associated records in the `category_link` db if its associated in the `category_a_id` or `category_b_id` column.

currently in the `category_links` model I have

```
belongs_to :category_b, :class_name => :Category
belongs_to :category_a, :class_name => :Category
```

and in the category db

```
has_many(:category_links, :foreign_key => :category_a_id, :dependent => :destroy)
has_many(:category_links, :foreign_key => :category_b_id, :dependent => :destroy)
```

But this only assosiates records from the `category_b_id` column with the matching id not from both. So calling `Category.find(1).category_links` doesnt grab records matching from both `category_a_id` and `category_b_id`. Same goes for destroying a category.

How can I get it to work so if I destroy a category it looks into both columns for the associated category and calling `Category.find(1).category_links` also looks in both columns for a matching record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no simple way to achieve that through `has_many`, but if you don't have to be fancy just create a custom method on `Category`:

```
def category_links
  @category_links ||= CategoryLinks.where('category_a_id = ? or category_b_id = ?', id, id)
end
```

Comment: Yea wasn't sure if it was possible or not considering I couldn't find anything on it. Happy to hear someone confirm it. I'll leave this open for a day to see what other answers come in. If nothing comes in I'll go with your response.